# Stubbing with WebMock not intercepting request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rspec-rails

I'm attempting to stub a request to a Controller using WebMock. However, as I'm creating the stub, the request isn't being intercepted the way I'd expect or want it to be.

The Controller does nothing but render JSON based on the query parameter:

```
def index      
  render json: MyThing.search(params[:query]).as_json(only: [:id], methods: [:name_with_path])
end
```

And the stubbing goes as follows:

```
mything_val = { ...json values... }
stub_request(:any, mything_path).with(query: { "query" => "a+thing" }).to_return(body: mything_val, status: 200)
page.find('.MyThingInput > input').set('a thing')

# Note: I've tried this with and without the `query:` parameter, as well as 
with and without specifying header info.
```

This is triggering a React component. What it does is, when a word or words are entered into the input, it sends an AJAX request to mything_path with the inputted value, which returns as JSON several suggestions as to what the user might mean. These are in a `li` element within `.MyThingInput-wrapper`.

In the spec file, I include:

```
require 'support/feature_helper'
require 'support/feature_matchers'
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!
```

What's actually happening when I input the text into the React component however is that regardless of the WebMock stub, it's hitting the Controller, making the DB request, and failing due to some restrictions of the testing environment. My understanding of how this should work is that when the request is made to mything_url, it should be intercepted by WebMock which would return the values I pre-defined, and never hit the Controller at all.

My guess is that somehow I'm mocking the wrong URI, but honestly, at this point I'm really uncertain. Any and all input is appreciated, and I'm happy to clarify any points I've made here. Thanks massively!

Comment: WebMock intercepts network requests to external servers (for example, a 3rd party API), not to your own server.

Comment: That would absolutely explain it. What would a good solution be then to intercept the request to the Controller? I've run into a different issue trying to use `allow_any_instance_of(MyController)`, but I can pursue that if that's best. Or perhaps VCR?

Comment: VCR is just a DSL that sits on top of WebMock, so it will have the same issue.  I would stub the search method on MyThing.  Something like: `allow(MyThing).to receive_message_change(:search, :as_json).and_return(json)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up solving my problem was stubbing out the model. I'd tried stubbing the Controller but ran into issues; however, this code did the trick:

```
before do
  mything_value = [{ "id" => "fb6135d12-e5d7-4e3r-b1h6-9bhirz48616", "name_with_path" => "New York|USA" }]
  allow(MyThing).to receive(:search).and_return(mything_value.to_json)
end
```

This way, it still hits the controller but stubs out the DB query, which was the real problem because it made use of Elasticsearch (not running in test mode.)

I'm not super happy about hard-coding the JSON like that, but I've tried a few other methods without success. Honestly, at this point I'm just going with what works.

Interestingly enough, I'd tried this method before Infused's suggestion, but couldn't quite get the syntax right; same went with stubbing out the Controller action. Went to bed, woke up, tried it again with what I *thought* was the same syntax, and it worked. I'm just going to slowly back away and thank the code gods.

Answer (score 0):

If elastic search is the problem, then maybe try

- installing Webmock

```
# in your gemfile
group :test do
gem 'webmock'
end
```

- stubbing out the requests to elasticsearch and returning the JSON

Something like this in spec_helper:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    WebMock.enable!
    WebMock.stub_request(:get, /#{ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/).to_return(body: File.read('spec/fixtures/elasticsearch/search-res.json'))ELASTICSEARCH_URL
    # and presumably, if you are using elasticsearch-rails, you'd want to stub out the updating as well:
    WebMock.stub_request(:post, /#{ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/).to_return(status: "200")
    WebMock.stub_request(:put, /#{ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/).to_return(status: "200")
    WebMock.stub_request(:delete, /#{ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/).to_return(status: "200")
  end
```

Of course, this stubs out all calls to elastic-search and returns the same JSON for all answers. Dig into the documentation for webmock if you need a different response for each query.